In R, how to reform a nested list from a dataframe after conversion with tibble::enframe %>% unlist?
I am working with highly nested named lists (from reading JSON files with jsonlite::fromJSON) and I found it hugely convenient to convert them to what I call a "linear dataframe" with unlist %>% tibble::enframe. It is useful because it allows me to perform some data wrangling on subsets without having to use complex recursive custom functions.
However, once I have edited the data, I can't find out how to reform the nested list from the "linear dataframe". Can someone help me with this ?
Here is a reproducible dummy example :
lst<-list(
  customers=list(
    A=1,
    B=2,
    C=3),
  providers=list(
    A=1,
    D=5),
  vehicles=list(
    a=NA,
    b=NA))

df<-enframe(unlist(lst))

df[grepl(x=df$name,pattern="vehicles\\.a"),"value"]<-8

#How to reform lst from df ?
lst<-deframe(df) ???


While it does take the recursive approach, {purrr} might still be worth a look. Your example would be tackled with lst |> assign_in(where = c("vehicles", "a"), 8) (see cheatsheet).

Using relist
First adding the required attributes with as.relistable
df <- tibble::enframe(unlist(as.relistable(lst)))

Change the value with your condition
df[grepl(x=df$name,pattern="vehicles\\.a"),"value"] <- 8

Getting the list back
relist(tibble::deframe(df))
$customers
$customers$A
[1] 1

$customers$B
[1] 2

$customers$C
[1] 3


$providers
$providers$A
[1] 1

$providers$D
[1] 5


$vehicles
$vehicles$a
[1] 8

$vehicles$b
[1] NA


attr(,"class")
[1] "relistable" "list"


This answer works if the final list must have the same structure as the starting list. I now have a case where I use dplyr::filter on the data-frame to remove sublistes, then I would like to reform the original list without those sublists.

Isn't that a new question?

It depends on what one means by "once I have edited the data".  In my case, edition not only mean modification but also subsetting. I can create a different question if you prefer ?

The title should still reflect the original problem and answer, but ultimately it's your decision.

Then I will open a new related question. I admit the orgininal problem did not mention explicitly subsetting.

Maybe use the CRAN package rjsoncons to stay with the JSON representation and use JSONPatch to update directly?
## start with `json` rather than `lst`
json = jsonlite::toJSON(lst, auto_unbox = TRUE)

Here's the patch operation
library(rjsoncons)
op = '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/vehicles/a", "value": 8}]'
json_patched = j_patch_apply(json, op)

This results in
> json_patched |> noquote()
[1] {"customers":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},"providers":{"A":1,"D":5},"vehicles":{"a":8,"b":null}}

The function j_patch_op() helps to formulate / validate the operation
op = j_patch_op("replace", "/vehicles/a", value = 8, auto_unbox = TRUE)

Patches can include several transformations as documented on the j_patch_op help page and in a vignette

This suggestion is appropriate for a few specific modifications. In my case, I would like to drop some elements or sublists using filter on the dataframe after unlist %>% enframe
